# SQL: Cross tab query to unpivot column names to rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008, oracle-sqldeveloper, crosstab

Sorry If I'm unclear. This is what I have:

[Table A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIX6I.jpg)

And this is what I want to achieve:

[Table B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6p0B.jpg)

Basically, instead of having a column for each item, I want to put all of the items under one column called Code. This will explode the number of rows I have, because each item has 3 or more different ratios (and all the percentages are also going under a Ratio column). I know how to transpose rows to columns and vice versa, but for this, I'm a little lost. Any help is kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using SQL Server (tags in your question are confusing since you have both mysql and sql-server) and if the number of codes is limited and known beforehand just use `UNPIVOT`

```
SELECT Type, Code, Ratio
  FROM 
( 
  SELECT Type, HRE, HRF, HRM
    FROM TableA 
) s
UNPIVOT
( 
  Ratio FOR Code IN (HRE, HRF, HRM) 
) u
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4eda1/7)**

Now if the number of codes is not known beforehand or just want do it dynamically you can use dynamic SQL

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF(
(
  SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(name)
    FROM sys.columns 
   WHERE object_id = object_id('TableA') 
     AND name LIKE 'H__'
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

SET @sql = 
'SELECT Type, Code, Ratio
  FROM 
( 
  SELECT Type, ' + @cols +
'    FROM TableA 
) s
UNPIVOT
( 
  Ratio FOR Code IN (' + @cols + ') 
) u'

EXECUTE(@sql)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4eda1/13)**

Comment: @rustynails Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Comment: you were of tremendous help. I can't believe I did not reply back. Thank you kind sir.